# Unable to load mysql dump file

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqldump, corruption

I recently had to deal with migrating some servers over (rather was forced to by the hosting company) and we took too long to migrate our data so they did it for us. Unfortunately they just copied `/var/lib/mysql` for the database. Which created all sorts of errors when trying to get the data working again. So I ran mysql in `innodb_force_recovery = 1` mode and was able to take dumps of all but 1 of my databases.

Then I completely uninstalled mysql and reinstalled and tried to import the dump files into the newly created databases.

**Then I got this error:**

```
ERROR 1030 (HY000) at line 810: Got error -1 from storage engine
```

So line 810 is the first data insert. It seems there is not problem creating tables, but anytime I try to insert I get that error. I can't seem to find any documentation on what that error means.

How do I go about resolving this error?

**Note:** After a bit more digging, it seems to be an error that only occurs with innodb tables. In fact I tried converting a myisam table to innodb and got the same exact error.

Comment: Run `SHOW ENGINES` please

Comment: Sorry, I figured this out. When I uninstalled and purged mysql it left my old /etc/mysql folder with my old my.cnf that had innodb_force_recovery still set, so I was unable to write to any innodb tables until I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**:

ERROR 1030 (HY000) at line 810: Got error -1 from storage engine

The above error means you have `innodb_force_recovery` set in your my.cnf
I'm not sure why I couldn't find this easily in mysql documentation, but it's simple enough.